# Android : Which method is better for navigational Listview (fragment or Listactivity)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, listactivity, android-tabs

I am a novice in developing android app ! I am working with *Android Studio*!
Want to implement a tab-panel in which some of the tabs (as [this](http://nathwebshop.com/images/promotion_images/device-2014-03-17-163849.png)) will contain listview to hold some data or image from a json Webservice! While the data comes from internet connectivity so there is performance is a issue for me!

I have got two types of way to implement tabs in android! One is [listactivity](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/android-combining-tab-layout-and-list-view/) & other is fragment! I just want to know which of these two way is efficient for implementing tabs on android??

Comment: Always go with fragments.. Because here we have single activity only and handle multiple fragments.

Comment: Fragments are Android's solution to creating reusable user interfaces. You can achieve some of the same things using activities and layouts (for example by using includes). However; fragments are wired in to the Android API, from HoneyComb, and up.

Comment: Thanks @Lokesh & @B Amiyo for your feedback :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A listActivity is an activity, and you cannot bind a different activity to each tab-panel, but you can put a different fragment on each panel (or use a single container, and just replace the fragments there with transactions).

You can also use another fragment to display the tab-interface at the top, which remains constant as the contents below changes.  Something you couldn't do if you were switching activities.

Comment: make sure to use the [support version](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html) to get compatibility on pre-3.0 devices.